# flutter render Html and math (latex and katex)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Hello Flutter community,

I'm currently working on a Flutter project and encountering difficulties rendering both HTML and Math LaTeX content within the app. I've tried a few packages, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired results.

Here's a snippet of the content I'm trying to render:

```
String htmlContent = "<p>This is a <b>bold</b> text.</p> $x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$";
```

I've attempted using packages like flutter_html for HTML rendering and flutter_math for Math LaTeX, but combining them seems to be causing issues. The HTML renders fine, but the Math LaTeX doesn't display correctly.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to properly render both HTML and Math LaTeX content in Flutter, or recommend a package that seamlessly handles both?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between all of the packages related to LaTex and HTML rendering, the [flutter_tex](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex) package works best for now. You can check [Latex App](https://github.com/sm-sayedi/latex_app) which uses this package.

Comment: helpful and its working $$ between can you help us to do with single $ between